# Web API not always returning JSONP data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sonarqube, jsonp

I've been working with the SonarQube web API and found an interesting discrepancy. For some API calls, setting the dataType as JSONP to get around CORS errors works fine and returns the data as JSONP and for others the data can only be returned as JSON which is prohibited because I'm making a cross-origin request. I was wondering if this was an error on my end or if this is intended?

For context, API calls to /api/resources can respond with JSONP but calls to /api/issues/search cannot.

```
      $.ajax({
        url: 'http://sonar.optum.com/api/resources?resource=IDWS-IdentificationWorkstation:master&metrics=coverage',
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: "jsonp"
      })
```

The above AJAX calls works successfully and returns JSONP data.

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://sonar.optum.com/api/issues/search?projectKeys=IDWS-IdentificationWorkstation:master',
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: "jsonp"
      })
```

This AJAX call does not.

Comment: If it doesn't serve jsonp, use a proxy

Comment: My mistake, their link on their website sent me here. I was under the impression this was how I was meant to contact them. Sorry about that!

Comment: @epascarello In my opinion, technical questions about developer tools are perfectly fitting into the StackOverflow platform. I think it is not necessary to contact the (paid) support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The internal implementation of the web api endpoints varies. In SonarQube < 6.0 some endpoints are written in ruby. And even in SonarQube 6.5 some endpoints are serialising json by using protobuf, others use a simple Stringbuilder.

Depending on the internal implementation, more ore less "JSON features" are provided.